# Getting libudev-dev to run try developing with bevy

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I've looked around somewhat extensively to try and troubleshoot this problem, currently I can't seem to locate the libudev-dev package. When running sudo apt-get install libudev-dev it tells me:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libudev-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 19.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 251 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libudev-dev amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.17
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_245.4-4ubuntu3.17_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

as you can see I attempted to try --fix-missing cause previously it was saying use this, I believe now that's just a "continue" instead of error out from this one package. I saw many recommendations online to ensure that you're properly updated so I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

These were giving me some issues and erroring out so I eventually got them to run without any errors and tried again. Even then I'm still unable to locate the libudev-dev package. I followed the link provided in the install blob:

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I followed the path specified and located a few versions that might possibly work for what I want but downloading them through that file navigator and running them said I was missing some dependencies but I've been unable to see what dependencies I don't have. So I attempted running it through terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev=251.4-1ubuntu6
```

that was giving me issues saying that version was not found, and I'm not all too familiar with the = syntax so I'm not sure what I could have done wrong there. I'm at my wits end with this, no idea what the problem could be and I was really excited to try out bevy and get some more rust experience, but I can't even compile the most basic app.

Some system information to possibly help debug:

```
uname -a
**redacted** INTEL 5.15.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 1 16:17:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/os-release

NAME="Zorin OS"
VERSION="16.1"
ID=zorin
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Zorin OS 16.1"
VERSION_ID="16"
HOME_URL="https://zorin.com/os/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.zorin.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://zorin.com/os/feedback/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://zorin.com/legal/privacy/"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

lscpu
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           151
Model name:                      12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12600KF

lspci
0000:03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 73ff (rev c1)
```